# Kotlin: prevent == with wrong types from compiling

Tags: kotlin

Let's consider the following simplified example:

```
interface I { /* some stuff */ }

object A: I { /* some stuff */ }

object B: I { /* some more stuff */ }

class Cell<J: I>(val n: Int, val j: J) {
   /* some more stuff that uses j */
   fun eq(c: Cell<J>): Boolean {
       return n == c.n
   }
}
```

Now `Cell(1, A).eq(Cell(2, A))` compiles, but `Cell(1, A).eq(Cell(2, B))` doesn't, as expected.

Now I want to replace `eq` with `==`. Sadly, the only way I see is the following:

```
class Cell<J: I>(val i: Int, val j: J) {
   override fun equals(c: Any?): Boolean {
       c as Cell<J>
       return i == c.i
   }
}
```

This has the disadvantage that `Cell(1, A) == Cell(2, B)` will happily compile. I can, of course, check at runtime whether j is the same, but I would like to know it before running the program. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you currently have is the solution. `equals` does not have any type safety.

With type safety, you wouldn't be able to properly compare types on different abstractions, unless you specified the higher-tiered type first:

```
class Sub : Super
class Super(val num: Int)

fun compare(sub: Sub, super: Super) {
    val superFirst = super == sub // would compile
    val subFirst = sub == super // wouldn't compile
}
```

So it doesn't make sense for `equals` to specify a strict parameter.

The `equals` function has an argument of `Any`, so you'll never receive type-safety from this. You cannot overload the operator either, as attempting to do so will throw an error.

`equals` sole purpose is to check for the equality at runtime (through potential type checks & state checks), so it wouldn't be the proper tool for this.

Comment: "it wouldn't be the proper tool for this", then what would be the proper tool? I was looking for something similar to how `==` works in Haskell.

Comment: @zabolekar What you have would be the proper tool. Kotlin doesn't aim to solve problems that can be easily solved with existing solutions. For example, the ternary operator, which many have requested, but declined due to `if` being an expression - lowering verbosity is a non-goal of Kotlin, as mentioned by the developers. A type-safe equals isn't generalized enough to actually be needed, especially when it comes bundled with the issues mentioned in my post. Thus, you cannot use `==` and expect type safety.

Comment: This specific problem could be worked around, but there are others.

Answer (score 2):

> I was looking for something similar to how == works in Haskell.

Even if you don't need it to be named `==`, this doesn't interoperate well with JVM subtyping, which Kotlin needs to support (and Haskell of course doesn't). It might be instructive to look at a failed attempt:

```
public infix fun <A> A.eq(x: A) = this == x
```

This requires the receiver and argument to have the same type `A`, so `1 eq ""` shouldn't compile, right? Wrong! The compiler "helpfully" infers `A` to be `Any`, which it couldn't do in Haskell.

Another issue: can you compare values of types `Interface1` and `Interface2`? They could be equal because both could belong to a class implementing both interfaces.

You *can* actually do it in Scala, because type inference works differently there, but I don't think a good solution exists for Kotlin.